# Phoenix.ActionClauseError at POST, no matching action clause to process request

Tags: rest, controller, elixir

I'm receiving this error whenever I POST to /api/subastas

```
Phoenix.ActionClauseError at POST /api/subastas/ bad request to IascSubastas.SubastaController.create, no matching action clause to process request
```

If I run mix phoenix.routes I see that :create is correctly routed to POST /api/subastas

This is the router.ex

```
defmodule IascSubastas.Router do
  use IascSubastas.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", IascSubastas do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  scope "/api", IascSubastas do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/subastas", SubastaController, except: [:new, :edit] do
      post "/cancelar", SubastaController, :cancelar
      resources "/ofertas", OfertaController, except: [:new, :edit]
    end
  end
end
```

and SubastaController

```
defmodule IascSubastas.SubastaController do
  use IascSubastas.Web, :controller

  alias IascSubastas.Subasta

  def index(conn, _params) do
    subastas = Repo.all from s in Subasta, preload: [:mejor_oferta]
    render(conn, "index.json", subastas: subastas)
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    subasta = Repo.get!(Subasta, id) |> Repo.preload(:mejor_oferta)
    render(conn, "show.json", subasta: subasta)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"subasta" => subasta_params}) do
    changeset = Subasta.changeset(%Subasta{mejor_oferta: nil}, subasta_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, subasta} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> put_resp_header("location", subasta_path(conn, :show, subasta))
        |> render("show.json", subasta: subasta)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(IascSubastas.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "subasta" => subasta_params}) do
    subasta = Repo.get!(Subasta, id) |> Repo.preload(:mejor_oferta)
    changeset = Subasta.changeset(subasta, subasta_params)

    case Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, subasta} ->
        render(conn, "show.json", subasta: subasta)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(IascSubastas.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  def cancelar(conn, %{"subasta_id" => id}) do
    subasta = Repo.get!(Subasta, id) |> Repo.preload(:mejor_oferta)
    changeset = Subasta.changeset(subasta, %{terminada: true})

    case Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, subasta} ->
        render(conn, "show.json", subasta: subasta)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(IascSubastas.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    subasta = Repo.get!(Subasta, id)

    # Here we use delete! (with a bang) because we expect
    # it to always work (and if it does not, it will raise).
    Repo.delete!(subasta)

    send_resp(conn, :no_content, "")
  end
end
```

I only get the error at http://localhost:4000/api/subastas/, any other URL works good.

Comment: Are you definitely sending JSON? Please check the content_type of your request.

Comment: missed that header when using Postman, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

content_type was missing in POST!  "application/json"

Answer (score -2):

I resolved, just added header.
My version:

```
% mix phoenix.new -v
Phoenix v1.2.1
% elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.3.2
```

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](//stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).